# About Sines in Programming

Tags: math, trigonometry

I am trying to understand trigonometry and the short answer is that I do not.

I drew a little triangle to mess around with and I asked myself the question, "If I know the length of the hypotenuse and the angle, how do I find the length of the other edges?".

Then I started reading. Apparently, the sine of angle A is supposed to equal the length of the opposite side divided by the length of the hypotenuse. So I figured that, using a right triangle, multiplying the length of the hypotenuse by the sine of the angle would yield the length of the opposing side.

1.414 / 1 = .707blahblah * 1.414 = 1 on my calculator.

But in every programming language I try sin(45.0) equals .8somethingsomething. I tried c++, c#, java, php, and lua.

Is the input not being interpreted as degrees? What unit is being used and how do I convert it? I've been seeing the word Radians, it would be helpful if someone could explain what a Radian is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radians are units of angular measure, like degrees, except that while there are 360 degrees in a circle, there are 2*pi (about 6.28) radians in a circle. You can convert degrees to radians by multiplying by pi (3.14159) and dividing by 180.

The formula works *if* the triangle is a right triangle, and yes, most programming languages expect radians rather than degrees as arguments to functions like `sin()` and `cos()`.

Regarding the argument in the comments below: if you fix angle <BAC, side AB, and side BC, you can see that there are two possible positions for point C which preserve the the length D2 for side BC. Therefore <BAC, D1, and D2 do *not* fully determine a triangle.

[image]

Comment: There are, however, equations that work regardless of whether or not the triangle is a right triangle.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: sure. Depends on what you know. You need to know either two sides and the angle between them, or two angles and the side between them, to determine a triangle. If you ostensibly know just one angle and the hypotenuse of a right triangle, you actually know all three angles, so you're all set.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the "between"; any combination of three pieces of information other than three angles gives you enough to determine the other three.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Not true, actually. An angle, one adjacent side, and the opposite side (i.e., you don't have the angle between the sides) do *not* determine a triangle -- draw a diagram if you're not sure. That side hanging off the end can rotate freely.

Comment: The known angle pins the side down.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: There's an XKCD where the guy is staying up all night because "someone is wrong on the Internet". I think this is one of those times :) See my edit above with a handy diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The input to `sin` functions generally is expected in radians, not degrees. For example, in the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin%28double%29) for `sin` it's stated that:

> Parameters:
>   a - an angle, in radians.

Convert the angle in degrees to radians first, by multiplying it by pi/180

Answer (score 1):

A [**radian**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) is the distance of the radius of a circle along its circumference. Since a circle's circumference is 2 times pi times its radius, there are 2 times pi radians in one complete circle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Those functions all take their input in radians, not degrees.

You can convert degrees to radians by multiplying the degrees by π/180.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to radians: Radian = degree/180*Pi

Comment: Without specifying a programming language, we can't tell whether you mean `degree/(180*pi)` or `(degree/180)*pi`.

Comment: Because of the equality of the order of operations, the statement isn't expected to read left to right?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert from degrees to radians, divide the number in degrees by 180 and multiply by pi.